# "Undefined reference" errors when linking in DMD

Tags: linker, d, ld, dmd, linker-errors

When I am compiling a program that requires the mondo library in D, I get slammed with a wall of errors from the linker. The last two lines, which are the only ones remotely legible are:

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Error: linker exited with status 1
```

All other lines prior to it, however, essentially say the same thing: "undefined reference to ..."

I've done my research about this problem before asking on Stack Overflow, but what worked for everybody else does not seem to work for me. (Of course, I had to look up this problem with C or C++ builds, but I imagine it is not significantly different.)

Everything elsewhere on the Internet says that I need to link my libraries after compiling them to objects, but I believe I am doing that and still getting the error. The command sequence I am using looks like this:

```
$ dmd -c ./source/mondo/source/* insert.d
```

then

```
$ dmd insert.o mondo.o mongoc.o bsond.o
```

(All of the files above besides insert.o come from ./source/mondo/source/*)

The header to my program looks like this, if it is worth anything:

```
import mondo;
import bsond;
import mongoc;
```

I don't see how I can possibly be more explicit to the compiler what I want, but I still seem to get this error.

Note: mondo requires mongo-c-driver to work. I compiled that library with no issues. I tried including it by passing

```
-L-L/usr/local/lib
```

to DMD, but that did not work, either. In fact, I just get what appear to be a bunch of "undefined reference" errors for functions in that library as well!

Comment: `-L-L/usr/local/lib` doesn't include a library, it includes a library path... and that's the default, so it does nothing. Try something like `-L-lmongo` - a lower case l and the library name (whatever the C one is) and see what happens. Also, actually posting the undefined reference lines, at least a few of them, can be a big help.